# Removing value from object in Angular 6

Tags: javascript, arrays, angular, typescript

I have some object in Angular like this

```
documents = [
{name: "sto.jpg", selected: false}
{name: "stosecen.jpg", selected: false}
{name: "red.png", selected: false}
{name: "maxresdefault.jpg", selected: false}
];
```

And some array like this

```
documentsForDelete = ["sto.jpg", "stosecen.jpg"];
```

I need to remove values from documents from documentsForDelete

This is what i have tried and no luck

```
  remove(array, element) {
    const index = array.indexOf(element);
    array.splice(index, 1);
  }

remove(documents.name, documentsForDelete);
```

Comment: The posted question does not appear to include [any attempt](https://idownvotedbecau.se/noattempt/) at all to solve the problem. StackOverflow expects you to [try to solve your own problem first](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592/how-much-research-effort-is-expected-of-stack-overflow-users), as your attempts help us to better understand what you want. Please edit the question to show what you've tried, so as to illustrate a specific roadblock you're running into a [MCVE]. For more information, please see [ask] and take the [tour].

Comment: I have tried and added my solution

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can get the resultant array using `.filter()`:

```js
let data = [
  {name: "sto.jpg", selected: false},
  {name: "stosecen.jpg", selected: false},
  {name: "red.png", selected: false},
  {name: "maxresdefault.jpg", selected: false}
];

let array = ["sto.jpg", "stosecen.jpg"];

let result = data.filter(({ name }) => !array.includes(name));

console.log(result);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```